# Could we move background image in css3 animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

Could we move background image instead of moving div by using css3 animation?

For example:

```
div{
width:800px;
position:relative;
background:url(image) no-repeat;
border:1px solid red;
-webkit-animation: mov 5s infinate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mov{
from{ top:0px left: 500px;}
to{ top:500px; left:500px;}
}
```

In this case div will move to `left:500px;` Could we move only background image?

Thanks to your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can, just use the `background-position` property:

```
@keyframes mov {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 100% 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the top and left attributes, set the background-position-x and background-position-y attributes.  Those two represent the "offset" of the background, so setting them will appear to move the background.